# Two infinitesimals infinitely close to each other compared to a third one?

Tags: definite-integrals, infinitesimals

On keisler's book, Elementary Calculus, he presented the following definition:

$\epsilon\ \approx\ \delta$ compared to $\Delta x$  if $\epsilon/ \Delta x \approx\ \delta\ / \Delta x$

and used it to prove the infinite sum theorem

$B(a, b) = \int_a^b h(x)\ dx$ if $\Delta B\ \approx\ h(x) \Delta x $ compared $ \Delta x$

Here's the proof:

[image]
[image]

And he kept using it to find formulas for different quantities: area, volume, .. etc. but he never assures the correctness of the  "$\Delta B\ \approx\ h(x) \Delta x$ compared $\Delta x$" part explicitly. Does he take that condition for granted as being intuitive in  proving the formulas he derived thereafter? Is there a way to assure it that I am missing?

Comment: Is the book trying to rigorously define integration? I'm not sure what it means by "compared to", but I think it's just saying that if a tiny sliver of area can be approximated to perfection by the tinier and tinier changes in x times the height of the "rectangle", then the area can be found by integration. I guess their definition also makes in intuitively clear that if ΔB ≈ h(x)Δx, then ΔB/Δx ≈ h(x), so the "derivative" of B is h(x).

Comment: He had already defined integration in an earlier chapter. He wants to find a formula for, say area, by first finding an infinitesimal area
$\Delta B\ =h(x) \Delta x\ $
then the total area is the integral of that function, and he wants a proved theorem to justify that step. At the beginning of the chapter he introducted to a counterexample to your assumption.
$3\Delta x\ \approx\ 2\Delta x\ $ but not compared to $\Delta x $

Comment: is it possible you could post a picture of the page where he talks about it or proves the infinite sum theorem?

Comment: I have added the proof.